How to return a custom response in case of error in webflux filter
return chain.filter(exchange).doOnError((throwable) -> {
            this.handleException(exchange, throwable);
        });

in the above code i would like to return a custom response eg as below
{
"its failed"
}

I tried it by returning it in the handleException method
 byte[] responseByte =
                        JsonUtils.getObjectMapper()
                                .writeValueAsString("its failed")
                                .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                DataBuffer buffer = exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap(responseByte);
                return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Flux.just(buffer));

But its not working and throwing the default exception
